# How to block home button on Android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, lockscreen, android-homebutton

On Android 4.4 I develop a lockscreen app, but in lockscreen activity I can't block home button. Can anyone solve it?

Answer (score -2):

Override the onKeyDown function of the activity and then catch the event for the home button.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```